# For a proper installation of .NET4, should its assemblies be in GAC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-4.0, gac

For a proper installation of .NET4, should its assemblies be in GAC?
I only see 2 and 3.5 in there.
Is there a technique to add all .NET4 dlls like System.Web.Extensions in the GAC?
Do I basically have to re-install it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GAC for .Net 4 is actually `%windir%\Microsoft.NET\assembly`.

[This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd727509.aspx) has additional information on the whys and wherefores in the `Know When to Use the GAC` section.

Answer (score 1):

the installer also places another copy of these files outside the GAC. From this location, they can simply be copied and pasted into the bin folder of the target application.

On my machine the required files are here:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET 2.0 AJAX Extensions\v1.0.61025\

The files I needed were:

System.Web.Extensions.Design.dll
System.Web.Extensions.dll